# Performing a multiplication, textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform with few comboboxes,texboxes etc...So I want to multiply the value from txtStake in txtTotal by clicking btnAdd, but everytime when I click btnAdd I want to multiply  the result too.

```
 //For example:
 //click-1, txtStake = 2, txtTotal = 2;
 //click-2, txtStake = 2, txtTotal = 4;
 //click-3, txtStake = 3, txtTotal = 12;
 //click-3, txtStake = 4.5 txtTotal = 54; Ok? How to do that? Thanks.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------

class Multy
{        
    public decimal Stake;

    public Multy()
    {}   
}

 private List<Multy> matches = new List<Multy>();

 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        matches = new List<Multy>();
        Multy match = new Multy();

        match.Stake = decimal.Parse(txtStake.Text);

        matches.Add(match);

        decimal l_Stake;

        string strStake;

        string strOutputLine;

        foreach (Multy m in matches)
        {              
            l_Stake = m.Stake;

            strStake = l_Stake.ToString();
        }
       txtTotal.text = //code?   
     }
```

Comment: You are creating a new (empty) `matches` list on every click. That's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you are adding one element to your list and then using foreach... If you want to multiply `txtStake` value with the current value of `txtTotal` then just do the following:

```
decimal result,value;
if(decimal.TryParse(txtStake.Text,out result) 
    && decimal.TryParse(txtTotal.Text,out value))
         txtTotal.Text = (result * value).ToString();
else if(decimal.TryParse(txtStake.Text,out result))
         txtTotal.Text = result.ToString();
```

Also your `Multy` class is totally pointless, you can use `List<decimal>`

Answer (score 0):

You basically asking for this (without error handling, feel free to improve it):

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stake = decimal.Parse(txtStake.Text);
    var total = decimal.Parse(txtTotal.Text); 
    total *= stake;
    txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
}
```

But there are a lot of things going in your code. `Multy`? `List`? `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
private List<Multy> matches = new List<Multy>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do NOT create a new 'matches' list, use the existing one
    Multy match = new Multy();
    match.Stake = decimal.Parse(txtStake.Text); 
    // you should use "TryParse" here, what if the user entered "A"?
    matches.Add(match);

    decimal runningTotal = 1m; // base value

    foreach (Multy m in matches)
    {              
        runningTotal = runningTotal * m.Stake;
    }
   txtTotal.text = runningTotal.ToString();  
 }
```